# Widgets and Screen Rotation in IOS

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an ipad app using storyboards which is laid out in landscape mode. All the labels and and imageviews are centered in the storyboard. It looks great in landscape mode, but as soon as the tablet is rotated, the ipad redraws the widgets using the landscape screen parameters, rather than the portrait mode ones. How do I get the widgets to redraw when in the correct mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto resizing to redraw your view to Portait mode.

Or

You can use `interfaceOrientation` to set a exact position for the views which is not aligned in Portait mode something like the code below

Note: Change Widgets frame only if it is improper.

Learn to position your views using auto resizing... which is more appreciated.

Animate it to have good orientation feel.

For ios 6 use`- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait|| 
             interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
   {
       //Code
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
            _btn1.frame = CGRectMake(190, 270, 137, 240);
            _btn2.frame = CGRectMake(440, 270, 137, 240);
            _btn3.frame = CGRectMake(300, 40, 137, 240);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        });

   }
   else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight||
                   interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
  {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        _btn1.frame = CGRectMake(250, 180, 137, 240);
        _btn2.frame = CGRectMake(640, 180, 137, 240);
        _btn3.frame = CGRectMake(440, 40, 137, 240);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    });

    //Code
}

return YES;

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is the point of using a Storyboard and Constraints if the UI requires special code to handle screen rotating? I looked up "auto resizing" but that seems to be only for ios 6 (I'm using ios7). I think maybe this is for AutoLayout?